# How databricks do auto scaling for a cluster

Tags: pyspark

I have a databricks cluster setup with auto scale upto 12 nodes. 
I have often observed databricks scaling cluster from 6 to 8, then 8 to 11 and then 11 to 14 nodes.

So my queries -
1. Why is it picking up 2-3 nodes to be added at one go 
2. Why auto scale is triggered as I see not many jobs are active or heavy processing on cluster. CPU usage is pretty low.
3. While auto scaling why is it leaving notebook in waiting state
4. Why is it taking up to 8-10 min to auto scale

Thanks

I am trying to investigate why data bricks is auto scaling cluster when its not needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a cluster, you can either provide a fixed number of workers for the cluster or provide a minimum and maximum number of workers for the cluster.

When you provide a fixed size cluster, Databricks ensures that your cluster has the specified number of workers. When you provide a range for the number of workers, Databricks chooses the appropriate number of workers required to run your job. This is referred to as **autoscaling**.

With autoscaling, Databricks dynamically reallocates workers to account for the characteristics of your job. Certain parts of your pipeline may be more computationally demanding than others, and Databricks automatically adds additional workers during these phases of your job (and removes them when they’re no longer needed).

Autoscaling makes it easier to achieve high cluster utilization, because you don’t need to provision the cluster to match a workload. This applies especially to workloads whose requirements change over time (like exploring a dataset during the course of a day), but it can also apply to a one-time shorter workload whose provisioning requirements are unknown. Autoscaling thus offers **two advantages:**

- Workloads can run faster compared to a constant-sized
  under-provisioned cluster.
- Autoscaling clusters can reduce overall costs compared to a
  statically-sized cluster.

Databricks offers **two types** of cluster node autoscaling: **standard** and **optimized**.

---

### How autoscaling behaves

Autoscaling behaves differently depending on whether it is optimized or standard and whether applied to an interactive or a job cluster.

#### Optimized

1. Scales up from min to max in 2 steps.
2. Can scale down even if the cluster is not idle by looking at shuffle
   file state.
3. Scales down based on a percentage of current nodes.
4. On job clusters, scales down if the cluster is underutilized over
   the last 40 seconds.
5. On interactive clusters, scales down if the cluster is underutilized
   over the last 150 seconds.

#### Standard

1. Starts with adding 4 nodes. Thereafter, scales up exponentially, but
   can take many steps to reach the max.
2. Scales down only when the cluster is completely idle and it has been
   underutilized for the last 10 minutes.
3. Scales down exponentially, starting with 1 node.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the details. Could you add more on 2/3/4 queries if possible please ?

Comment: Official docs on autoscaling, for latest info: https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#cluster-size-and-autoscaling Unfortunately the specific algorithms for up/downscaling is not explained in detail here.